# How to iterate over a char pointer array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

How do I iterate over my files variable in an efficient way ?

Should I add NULL as my last value, or do something else ?

```
char *files[] =
        {
            "c1.txt",
            "r1.txt",
            "t2.c",
            "d.cpp",
        };
```

Comment: You can, yes. (I would add NULL though, not 'NULL'). Or you can remember that this here list has 4 entries. Or you use `sizeof(files) / sizeof(char*)`. Etc.

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: Assume by "parse" you mean "iterate", yes, that is one option. Is that *really* your problem?

Comment: `files` is an array and you can get the size of this array using `sizeof` operator to iterate over.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Yes, I added only 4 entries - It has around 200 entries.  I need to iterate and find out whether some user given entry matches any of them on this list  @Mr Lister - Please move your comment as answer. thanks

Comment: @user444 OK, answer given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several possibilities.

- You can add `NULL` as the final entry, as you suggest yourself
- If the array comes from another source (like a file on disk), just keep a counter of the number of lines you're reading
- But if the array is given in the source, its length is constant and you can just check how many elements it has (by subtracting the line numbers)
- Also, the size of a constant array is `sizeof(files) / sizeof(char*)`.

Comment: But note, if the array is passed as an **argument** to a function, the array argument with decay to a pointer and you can no longer use `sizeof files/sizeof *files` in the function. (I know you know, this is for the OP)

Answer (score 0):

You could also define a macro like

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE(a) (sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]))
...
int i;
for(i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE(files); i++)
{
    printf("%s\n", files[i]);
}
```

this should work for any sort of array, regardless of type.